# Where would it be appropriate to ask a question about a basic privacy policy for a web developer’s portfolio website?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

So here is the actual question that I would like to ask somewhere on the Stack Exchange network: I’ve dealt with creation of privacy policies for various public facing websites over the years. Requirements are wording are similar, but typically address the core functionality of a website as an entity collection data for business and/or advertising purposes.

Now as a web developer who is creating some simple “sandbox” ideas/tools to show off on my online portfolio, is there a privacy policy out there that would address the simply stated fact:

> “I’m a web developer, this is my portfolio website and I do not
>   collect any data past the sundry data passed along by a web browser
>   when it accesses my site for development purposes.”

So that is basically my question; might be hastily worded, but it’s my question. The meta-question being asked here is simply this: **Now where on Stack Exchange would this be appropriate to ask?**

- Would it be [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)?
- Or maybe [Software Engineering](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com)?
- Or somewhere else like the [law Stack Exchange](http://law.stackexchange.com)?

This question—about the privacy policy question—stems from me signing up for various web service APIs where I have been granted basic access during my initial signup, but additional access/permissions requires a very clearly stated and linked privacy policy. And—again—my usage is to just show off my programming skills in a personal portfolio. I would imagine I’m not the only software developer in a situation like this.

Comment: Someone could probably do a lot of people a favor if they came up with a Creative Commons equivalent for privacy policies (and maybe ToS too).

Comment: This would fit better on the main meta, imo. You probably want an answer from *members* of the SE they recommend.

Comment: Regarding your example question ("Is there a privacy policy out there...") I would answer: "Yes, as soon as you put such a policy out". So I guess the question would not be good question almost anywhere. And I guess it depends in which aspects you're interested in. If you want to have it legally tight, ask on law...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My first instinct would be to say Law, but as I don't even have an account there I don't feel I'm qualified to say for definite. It would probably be worth asking this question on their meta.

It certainly doesn't belong on Stack Overflow—while we probably have an opinion it would be just that, an opinion.

I don't think it would work on Software Engineering either, particularly not since we restated our scope in clearer terms to go with the name change.

Answer (score 14):

Since you're asking specifically about a privacy policy *for a website*, I'd suggest [Webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com).  You might want to check out their [privacy-policy](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/privacy-policy) tag first, though, to see if something close to your question has been asked already.

Answer (score -9):

Another couple of places I'd suggest: [Information Security](http://security.stackexchange.com) (a stretch) and [Startups](http://startups.stackexchange.com) if applicable.